# how to make background of Drupal blocks transparent

Tags: theming

I just successfully added a background paper texture to my drupal site
  using the BackgroundImages module. https://drupal.org/project/bg_image
 One remaining issue I have is that the blocks themselves on my pages still have a solid white background. Can someone direct me on how to change the background of my drupal blocks to transparent?

Comment: You will need to modify the CSS of your theme.  There are a number of different ways to do this depending on your skill level.  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I was hoping to do this through a module settings. But it seems hacking the CSS is the only way. The responder below gave me some direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change background color use `background-color: transparent`

Also for example you can use

```
.block {
 background: none transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was originally hoping there could be a way to do this without digging into the CSS. But now I have some direction on how to find the CSS for individual blocks to perform the tweaks manually.

Comment: If you only have a few lines of CSS to change you can use the CSS Injector module: https://drupal.org/project/css_injector